# Stripe - using PaymentIntents and Stripe Elements with SCA

Tags: stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe and have found that I need to use the [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents) version to comply with [Strong Customer Authentication (SCA)](https://stripe.com/guides/strong-customer-authentication) when it is launched later this year.

My website will be taking one-off payments of between £25-75. I wanted to use Stripe Elements to display a slick horizontal form like this:

[image]

However when browsing the documentation for PaymentIntents I saw this note on the page:

[image]

What happens if I don't provide any of this information? My guess is it would decline the transaction, but I can't find anywhere in the docs where it would give me a sample error response for not providing this information.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason for providing this kind of information is it allows the processor and bank to do a real-time, risk-based analysis of a transaction, which can potentially qualify it for exception from SCA.

Stripe talks about it here: https://stripe.com/guides/strong-customer-authentication#low-risk-transactions

And transaction risk analysis is discussed in this PSD2 / SCA brief by J.P. Morgan https://www.jpmorgan.com/jpmpdf/1320745288478.pdf

In cases where information is not provided and the user does not authenticate via additional means, I suspect you'll simply see a normal decline here. You may also want to contact Stripe directly for more specifics about their system.

Answer (score -2):

additing to the above answer, make sure you added serverside webhook to validate payment in your end